# Show buddy when offline

Tags: pidgin

In Pidgin, if a buddy is online, I can right click "Show When 
Offline", and I'll continue seeing the buddy in my list when he logs 
off.

However, what if the buddy is offline when I want to do this?

I can right click on the buddy group and "Show When Offline" to see 
ALL offline buddies, but when I right click on one of them, the option 
is now "Hide When Offline".

I realize I could create a special "show when offline" group, but is 
there a way to show specific offline buddies without changing their 
group, and without waiting for them to come online first.

Answer (score 9):

Buddies > Show > Offline buddies :-) (You can hide them again when you're done.)